# Get-DistributionGroup with powershell

Tags: powershell

Hello Guys，I have a distribution group and it includes many sub-group，some of these groups have been set “AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom”，How can I use script to check all group to find which has been set AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom？

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
Get-DistributionGroup | Where-Object {$_.AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom}
```

Comment: Or shorter: `... | where AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom`